# Visual Studio C++ 2022 build fails without error message on Mac network share

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, samba

Ever since I updated Visual Studio 2022 from 17.1 to 17.2, I have been having a problem with my C++ project build failing without emitting an error message in the IDE Output window, no matter the diagnostic level selected in the `Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build Options` menu.

I have tried:

- Reinstalling Visual Studio 2022
- Deleting `.vs` folders(s)
- Deleting the `x64` folder

These are all suggested in answers to similar questions from several years ago that I have read here.

It definitely seems to have something to do with being on a network share from my Mac. I cloned my repository locally and the problem went away. Meanwhile, I cloned my repository to a different directory on the network share, and it continued to fail in the new directory.

I have discovered an error message buried in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp` in a file named `MSBuild_pid-<guid>.failure.txt`. It appears to be correlated to the failure. Here is the error message:

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTIONS FROM PROCESS 624:
=====================
6/20/2022 8:49:39 AM
Microsoft.Build.Framework.LoggerException: Failed to write to log file "Y:\<filepath>.log". IO operation will not work. Most likely the file will become too long or the handle was not opened to support synchronous IO operations.
   at Microsoft.Build.Logging.FileLogger.Write(String text)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ParallelConsoleLogger.WriteMessageAligned(String message, Boolean prefixAlreadyWritten, Int32 prefixAdjustment)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ParallelConsoleLogger.ErrorHandler(Object sender, BuildErrorEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildErrorEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, BuildErrorEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.MuxLogger.SubmissionRecord.RaiseErrorEvent(Object sender, BuildErrorEventArgs buildEvent)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.EventSourceSink.RaiseErrorEvent(Object sender, BuildErrorEventArgs buildEvent)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.LoggingService.RouteBuildEvent(KeyValuePair`2 nodeEvent)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.LoggingService.RouteBuildEvent(Object loggingEvent)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.LoggingService.LoggingEventProcessor(Object loggingEvent)
===================
```

This is similar to a question I posed a couple of weeks ago, but since the nature of the question is now more focused and has an apparent error message, I deleted that question and am reposting this issue as a new question for visibility and to avoid confusion.

[EDIT]

I decided to go fish out the actual log file in the message above. It turns out Visual Studio is not having any trouble writing to it. And it terminates in another error message:

```
  RGPLua.cpp
  RGPLuaConnector.cpp
  RGPLuaConnectorBase.cpp
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\type_traits(59,92): fatal error C1001: Internal compiler error.
```

It is unclear to me which message is the cause and which is the effect. However, after running it several times it is worth noting that the error and file location given in the log file is different each time while the message in the `MSBuild_pid` file is always the same.

Comment: Wasn't the comments on the previous question pointing to a samba configuration problem with building from a network share? Do you really need to build from a network share instead of building locally?

Comment: The samba config problem pointed to was out of date with respect to macOS. It appears that macOS has completely changed how samba is configured in the intervening years. At any rate it doesn't use the `smb.conf` file any more, so far as I can tell. The DX with a local copy is very degraded, and since this problem was introduced with 17.2 I would like to figure out a fix rather than a workaround.

Comment: ***At any rate it doesn't use the smb.conf file any more.*** I am not sure how it works on macOS but it certainly does use smb.conf on linux.

Comment: Precisely. MacOS is gradually rewriting the whole Unix environment, it seems.

Comment: ***I would like to figure out a fix rather than a workaround.*** It may be something that Microsoft changed with the file handling that breaks using samba.

Comment: Internal Compiler error should mean you found a bug in the compiler.

Comment: I don't doubt it *is* a compiler bug, but after running this several times it appears that both the file location and error message given in the log file is random. However the message in the MSBuild_pid file is always the same.